# Exchange limit and analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

The general question is:

> What can be said about the exchange of limit and analytic continuation?

I specify the general question to an example, even though I'm mainly interested in the former one. Let $f_n(z) \rightarrow f(z)$ be a sequence of complex analytic functions converging uniformly in some compact domain $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with an accumulation point. Assume that every $f_n(z)$ can be analytically continued on $B \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to $F_n(z)$.

Under which hypothesis can I conclude that there exists an analytic continuation $F(z)$ of $f(z)$ and there is (pointwise or uniform) convergence $F_n(z) \rightarrow F(z)$?

I ask the question because, quite surprisingly, I couldn't find information on the web. Comments and references are very welcome!

Comment: The Riemann Zeta function is a famous example where $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly for $\Re(z) \ge 1+\varepsilon$ but diverges for $\Re(z) < 1$ even though it can be analytically continued there.

Comment: @mercio Thanks for the observation! This doesn't seem to leave much room for positive statements...